# How to signout a user if the user is not active since last 15 minutes devise activeadmin

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, activeadmin, session-timeout

I have to logout a user(admin_user) if the user(admin_user) is not using the application for 15 minutes. How it can be done? I have tried installing activeadmin in my vendor and overriding it(putting devise.rb inside initializers folder inside vendor and write set timeout it did not work), but I don't know how that works. Please help me. I cannot write it in devise.rb as it is done via normal login(user).

Also I have one more query, how the main navigation bar can be changed in activeadmin? I need two menu one in main navigation bar and according sub navigation. Is this achievable through activeadmin?

Comment: You should ask two questions for two questions you have)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether this is the correct way of getting layouts, but I found the solution creating my_navigation resource in active admin.

```
class MyNavigation < ActiveAdmin::Component
  def build(namespace, menu)
    if current_admin_user
    render :partial => "/layouts/admin_header"
            else
            render :partial => "/layouts/company_admin_header"
            end
        end

end
```

Answer (score 4):

Jut use  `config.timeout_in = 15.minutes` in your `devise.rb` initializer.
Active admin has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Hello roman, thanks for your answer. I am using two user session for the application say user model for normal login and admin_user for admin login. what happens in that case?